# AWS Lambda and S3 trigger event data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, s3-bucket

I have a lambda function that I need to run eveytime there is a change in my s3 Bucket. I have added the trigger and it is working just fine, but I was wondering if there is any way to limit the scope the lambda function is to be run... for example Instead of running over the entire bucket, it runs only in the folder (inside the bucket) that change has been made?! or something like that..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this AWS announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-s3-adds-prefix-and-suffix-filters-for-lambda-function-triggering/), you can add prefix or suffix restrictions for S3 event triggers.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify rules:

```
- s3:
  bucket: photos
  event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
  rules:
    - prefix: uploads/
    - suffix: .jpg
```

See the `functions/events/s3` section in the [yml definition](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/).